# How to provide a dynamic value in a server component

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

The following works. But I am trying to pass in the param

to the getData function dependant on a value from a drop down selection.

Once selected, selected String value is added to state via zustand.

How can I use that state value here instead of 'customFlag' string?

I could of course perform this inside `ShowResult` component using `useEffect` and `'use client'`.

But defeats the purpose of server components in NextJS 13. Pls advice.

P.S: Using Next JS version 13.4.3.

```
// inside pages folder

const Home = async () => {
  const result = await getData('customFlag');
  return (
    <main className='container'>
      <ShowResult result={result} />
    </main>
  );
};
```

Comment: If the string value is created as part of user interaction, then it's not possible for the server component to have access to that. You will need to use a client component.